# Получить таблицу экспорта библиотеки dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Как получить таблицу экспорта системной библиотеки, желательно с адресами функций? Искал в книге Рихтера, но там нету.

Comment: Почитайте про структуру PE- заголовка, например [здесь](http://cs.usu.edu.ru/docs/pe/dirs1.html)

Comment: @AlexeyVesker там есть функции OpenPEFile(), GetHeader(), GetFilePointer(), ClosePEFile() а какой для них заголовочный файл?

Comment: Ни в каком, это функции написанные автором статьи, которую я привел в качестве отправной точки для изучения. Там, собственно, описан алгоритм того, как извлекать из таблицы экспорта (и не только) необходимую  вам информацию. Более подробно можно почитать в MSDN. Полноценный пример сейчас привести не смогу, но общий смысл такой: открываете его как обычный файл (только для чтения), проецируете в память, используя CreateFileMapping(), а дальше зная структуру файла и смещение нужных секций относительно начала файла извлекаете нужную вам информацию.

Comment: Вариант проще:  можно попробовать поискать готовые либы для этого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня сохранился небольшой код для получения таблицы экспорта. Он только для 32-битной системы (компилировать также надо как 32-битный бинарник), возможно под 64-битную его доработать не очень сложно будет.

Структура использованная в коде `PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` определена в моей системе в инклюде `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\winnt.h`.

Код выводит все имена экспорта плюс адреса функций. Вызывать программу нужно передав имя DLL. Для примера смотрите ниже дамп с выводом для `winmm.dll`.

Как помечено в `winnt.h` выводимые адреса являются "RVA from base of image" (RVA = Relative Virtual Address). Т.е. эти адреса это относительные смещения относительно базового адреса DLL.

Отдаю код на свой страх и риск, т.к. в нём особо не разбираюсь, просто нашёл у себя в базе исходников рабочей. Также сообщу что на мой взгляд таблица имён верна, а вот таблица адресов какая то странная, нужно ещё перепроверить то ли что надо это, прилагаю в конце вывод этой программы и вывод команды `dumpbin /exports winmm.dll` для сравнения.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    assert(argc >= 2);
    HMODULE lib = LoadLibraryEx(argv[1], NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
    assert(((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lib)->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE);
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS header = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((BYTE *)lib + ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lib)->e_lfanew);
    assert(header->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE);
    assert(header->OptionalHeader.NumberOfRvaAndSizes > 0);
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exports = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((BYTE *)lib + header->
        OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);
    assert(exports->AddressOfNames != 0);
    BYTE** names = (BYTE**)((int)lib + exports->AddressOfNames);
    BYTE** functions = (BYTE**)((int)lib + exports->AddressOfFunctions);
    for (int i = 0; i < exports->NumberOfNames; i++)
        printf("%s %p\n", (BYTE *)lib + (int)names[i], (BYTE *)lib + (int)functions[i]);
}
```

Пример вывода для `winmm.dll`:

```
CloseDriver 7310BE20
DefDriverProc 7310D570
DriverCallback 7310BD80
DrvGetModuleHandle 7310BDA0
GetDriverModuleHandle 73103E10
NotifyCallbackData 7310BDC0
OpenDriver 7310BDE0
PlaySound 73106FC0
PlaySoundA 7310BE00
PlaySoundW 7310BE20
SendDriverMessage 73113D40
WOW32DriverCallback 73102670
WOW32ResolveMultiMediaHandle 7310BE30
WOWAppExit 73107B00
aux32Message 73107C60
auxGetDevCapsA 731144D0
auxGetDevCapsW 73107DC0
auxGetNumDevs 7310BE50
auxGetVolume 7310BE70
auxOutMessage 7310BE90
auxSetVolume 7310BEA0
joy32Message 7310BEC0
joyConfigChanged 7310BEE0
joyGetDevCapsA 73107F70
joyGetDevCapsW 7310BF00
joyGetNumDevs 7310BF20
joyGetPos 7310BF40
joyGetPosEx 7310BF60
joyGetThreshold 7310BF90
joyReleaseCapture 7310BF70
joySetCapture 7310BFB0
joySetThreshold 7310BFD0
mci32Message 7310BFF0
mciDriverNotify 7310C010
mciDriverYield 7310BC30
mciExecute 73111D30
mciFreeCommandResource 73111D60
mciGetCreatorTask 73110050
mciGetDeviceIDA 73112120
mciGetDeviceIDFromElementIDA 73112170
mciGetDeviceIDFromElementIDW 731121C0
mciGetDeviceIDW 73112200
mciGetDriverData 731122D0
mciGetErrorStringA 731122F0
mciGetErrorStringW 7310E620
mciGetYieldProc 7310E700
mciLoadCommandResource 73112370
mciSendCommandA 731101D0
mciSendCommandW 7310E970
mciSendStringA 7310F190
mciSendStringW 7310F290
mciSetDriverData 7310F440
mciSetYieldProc 73112870
mid32Message 731128F0
midiConnect 73108170
midiDisconnect 7310C030
midiInAddBuffer 7310C050
midiInClose 7310C070
midiInGetDevCapsA 7310C090
midiInGetDevCapsW 7310C0B0
midiInGetErrorTextA 7310C0D0
midiInGetErrorTextW 7310C0F0
midiInGetID 7310C110
midiInGetNumDevs 7310C130
midiInMessage 7310C150
midiInOpen 7310C160
midiInPrepareHeader 7310C180
midiInReset 7310C1A0
midiInStart 7310C1C0
midiInStop 7310C1E0
midiInUnprepareHeader 7310C200
midiOutCacheDrumPatches 7310C220
midiOutCachePatches 7310C240
midiOutClose 7310C260
midiOutGetDevCapsA 7310C280
midiOutGetDevCapsW 7310C2A0
midiOutGetErrorTextA 7310C2C0
midiOutGetErrorTextW 7310C2E0
midiOutGetID 7310C300
midiOutGetNumDevs 7310C320
midiOutGetVolume 7310C340
midiOutLongMsg 7310C350
midiOutMessage 7310C370
midiOutOpen 73104310
midiOutPrepareHeader 7310C390
midiOutReset 7310C3B0
midiOutSetVolume 7310C3D0
midiOutShortMsg 7310C3F0
midiOutUnprepareHeader 7310C410
midiStreamClose 7310C430
midiStreamOpen 7310C450
midiStreamOut 7310C470
midiStreamPause 7310C490
midiStreamPosition 7310C4B0
midiStreamProperty 7310C4D0
midiStreamRestart 7310C4F0
midiStreamStop 7310C510
mixerClose 7310C530
mixerGetControlDetailsA 7310C550
mixerGetControlDetailsW 7310C570
mixerGetDevCapsA 7310C590
mixerGetDevCapsW 7310C5B0
mixerGetID 7310C5D0
mixerGetLineControlsA 7310C5F0
mixerGetLineControlsW 7310C610
mixerGetLineInfoA 7310C630
mixerGetLineInfoW 7310C650
mixerGetNumDevs 7310C670
mixerMessage 7310C690
mixerOpen 7310C6A0
mixerSetControlDetails 7310C6C0
mmDrvInstall 7310C6E0
mmGetCurrentTask 7310C700
mmTaskBlock 7310C720
mmTaskCreate 7310C730
mmTaskSignal 7310C740
mmTaskYield 7310C760
mmioAdvance 7310C780
mmioAscend 7310C790
mmioClose 7310C7B0
mmioCreateChunk 7310C7D0
mmioDescend 7310C7F0
mmioFlush 7310C810
mmioGetInfo 7310C830
mmioInstallIOProcA 7310C850
mmioInstallIOProcW 7310C870
mmioOpenA 7310C890
mmioOpenW 7310C8B0
mmioRead 7310C8D0
mmioRenameA 7310C8F0
mmioRenameW 7310C910
mmioSeek 7310C930
mmioSendMessage 7310C950
mmioSetBuffer 7310C970
mmioSetInfo 7310C990
mmioStringToFOURCCA 7310C9B0
mmioStringToFOURCCW 7310C9D0
mmioWrite 7310C9F0
mmsystemGetVersion 7310CA10
mod32Message 731146E0
mxd32Message 73108320
sndPlaySoundA 731085A0
sndPlaySoundW 731140C0
tid32Message 731140E0
timeBeginPeriod 731089D0
timeEndPeriod 73104330
timeGetDevCaps 7310CA30
timeGetSystemTime 7310CA50
timeGetTime 7310CA70
timeKillEvent 73103210
timeSetEvent 731039F0
waveInAddBuffer 731036B0
waveInClose 7310CA90
waveInGetDevCapsA 7310CAB0
waveInGetDevCapsW 7310CAD0
waveInGetErrorTextA 7310CAF0
waveInGetErrorTextW 7310CB10
waveInGetID 7310CB30
waveInGetNumDevs 7310CB50
waveInGetPosition 73104350
waveInMessage 7310CB70
waveInOpen 731042D0
waveInPrepareHeader 7310CB90
waveInReset 7310CBB0
waveInStart 7310CBD0
waveInStop 7310CBF0
waveInUnprepareHeader 7310CC10
waveOutBreakLoop 7310CC30
waveOutClose 7310CC50
waveOutGetDevCapsA 73104210
waveOutGetDevCapsW 7310CC70
waveOutGetErrorTextA 7310CC90
waveOutGetErrorTextW 7310CCB0
waveOutGetID 7310CCD0
waveOutGetNumDevs 7310CCF0
waveOutGetPitch 73104360
waveOutGetPlaybackRate 7310CD10
waveOutGetPosition 7310CD30
waveOutGetVolume 7310CD50
waveOutMessage 7310CD70
waveOutOpen 731042F0
waveOutPause 73103E90
waveOutPrepareHeader 7310CD90
waveOutReset 731041F0
waveOutRestart 73104230
waveOutSetPitch 7310CDB0
waveOutSetPlaybackRate 7310CDD0
waveOutSetVolume 7310CDF0
waveOutUnprepareHeader 7310CE10
waveOutWrite 731041D0
wid32Message 731041B0
wod32Message 73108BE0
```

Вывод `dumpbin /exports winmm.dll`:

```
  Section contains the following exports for WINMM.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    5632C80F time date stamp Fri Oct 30 04:29:51 2015
        0.00 version
           2 ordinal base
         181 number of functions
         180 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          4    0 00005B30 CloseDriver
          5    1 00005B40 DefDriverProc
          6    2 00005B50 DriverCallback
          7    3 00005B60 DrvGetModuleHandle
          8    4 00005B70 GetDriverModuleHandle
          9    5 00005B90 OpenDriver
         10    6 00005B80 PlaySound
         11    7 0000E7C0 PlaySoundA
         12    8 00001900 PlaySoundW
         13    9 00005BA0 SendDriverMessage
         14    A 0000FC10 WOWAppExit
         15    B 00005BB0 auxGetDevCapsA
         16    C 00005BC0 auxGetDevCapsW
         17    D 00005BD0 auxGetNumDevs
         18    E 00005BE0 auxGetVolume
         19    F 00005BF0 auxOutMessage
         20   10 00005C00 auxSetVolume
         21   11 00005C10 joyConfigChanged
         22   12 00005C20 joyGetDevCapsA
         23   13 00005C30 joyGetDevCapsW
         24   14 00005C40 joyGetNumDevs
         25   15 00005C60 joyGetPos
         26   16 00005C50 joyGetPosEx
         27   17 00005C70 joyGetThreshold
         28   18 00005C80 joyReleaseCapture
         29   19 00005C90 joySetCapture
         30   1A 00005CA0 joySetThreshold
         31   1B 0000C0D0 mciDriverNotify
         32   1C 0000C0F0 mciDriverYield
          3   1D 00006E50 mciExecute
         33   1E 0000A000 mciFreeCommandResource
         34   1F 0000C550 mciGetCreatorTask
         35   20 0000C5B0 mciGetDeviceIDA
         36   21 0000C600 mciGetDeviceIDFromElementIDA
         37   22 0000C650 mciGetDeviceIDFromElementIDW
         38   23 0000C750 mciGetDeviceIDW
         39   24 0000C780 mciGetDriverData
         40   25 000082E0 mciGetErrorStringA
         41   26 00008400 mciGetErrorStringW
         42   27 0000C820 mciGetYieldProc
         43   28 0000A1F0 mciLoadCommandResource
         44   29 00008700 mciSendCommandA
         45   2A 00008F90 mciSendCommandW
         46   2B 000090C0 mciSendStringA
         47   2C 000092D0 mciSendStringW
         48   2D 0000CE00 mciSetDriverData
         49   2E 0000CEB0 mciSetYieldProc
         50   2F 00005CB0 midiConnect
         51   30 00005CC0 midiDisconnect
         52   31 00005CD0 midiInAddBuffer
         53   32 00005CE0 midiInClose
         54   33 00005CF0 midiInGetDevCapsA
         55   34 00005D00 midiInGetDevCapsW
         56   35 00005D10 midiInGetErrorTextA
         57   36 00005D20 midiInGetErrorTextW
         58   37 00005D30 midiInGetID
         59   38 00005D40 midiInGetNumDevs
         60   39 00005D50 midiInMessage
         61   3A 00005D60 midiInOpen
         62   3B 00005D70 midiInPrepareHeader
         63   3C 00005D80 midiInReset
         64   3D 00005D90 midiInStart
         65   3E 00005DA0 midiInStop
         66   3F 00005DB0 midiInUnprepareHeader
         67   40 00005DC0 midiOutCacheDrumPatches
         68   41 00005DD0 midiOutCachePatches
         69   42 00005DE0 midiOutClose
         70   43 00005DF0 midiOutGetDevCapsA
         71   44 00005E00 midiOutGetDevCapsW
         72   45 00005E10 midiOutGetErrorTextA
         73   46 00005E20 midiOutGetErrorTextW
         74   47 00005E30 midiOutGetID
         75   48 00005E40 midiOutGetNumDevs
         76   49 00005E50 midiOutGetVolume
         77   4A 00005E60 midiOutLongMsg
         78   4B 00005E70 midiOutMessage
         79   4C 00005E80 midiOutOpen
         80   4D 00005E90 midiOutPrepareHeader
         81   4E 00005EA0 midiOutReset
         82   4F 00005EB0 midiOutSetVolume
         83   50 00005EC0 midiOutShortMsg
         84   51 00005ED0 midiOutUnprepareHeader
         85   52 00005EE0 midiStreamClose
         86   53 00005EF0 midiStreamOpen
         87   54 00005F00 midiStreamOut
         88   55 00005F10 midiStreamPause
         89   56 00005F20 midiStreamPosition
         90   57 00005F30 midiStreamProperty
         91   58 00005F40 midiStreamRestart
         92   59 00005F50 midiStreamStop
         93   5A 00005F60 mixerClose
         94   5B 00005F70 mixerGetControlDetailsA
         95   5C 00005F80 mixerGetControlDetailsW
         96   5D 00005F90 mixerGetDevCapsA
         97   5E 00005FA0 mixerGetDevCapsW
         98   5F 00005FB0 mixerGetID
         99   60 00005FC0 mixerGetLineControlsA
        100   61 00005FD0 mixerGetLineControlsW
        101   62 00005FE0 mixerGetLineInfoA
        102   63 00005FF0 mixerGetLineInfoW
        103   64 00006000 mixerGetNumDevs
        104   65 00006010 mixerMessage
        105   66 00006020 mixerOpen
        106   67 00006030 mixerSetControlDetails
        107   68 00006040 mmDrvInstall
        108   69 00006050 mmGetCurrentTask
        109   6A 00006060 mmTaskBlock
        110   6B 00006070 mmTaskCreate
        111   6C 00006080 mmTaskSignal
        112   6D 00006090 mmTaskYield
        113   6E 000060A0 mmioAdvance
        114   6F 000060B0 mmioAscend
        115   70 000060C0 mmioClose
        116   71 000060D0 mmioCreateChunk
        117   72 000060E0 mmioDescend
        118   73 000060F0 mmioFlush
        119   74 00006100 mmioGetInfo
        120   75 00006110 mmioInstallIOProcA
        121   76 00006120 mmioInstallIOProcW
        122   77 00006130 mmioOpenA
        123   78 00006140 mmioOpenW
        124   79 00006150 mmioRead
        125   7A 00006160 mmioRenameA
        126   7B 00006170 mmioRenameW
        127   7C 00006180 mmioSeek
        128   7D 00006190 mmioSendMessage
        129   7E 000061A0 mmioSetBuffer
        130   7F 000061B0 mmioSetInfo
        131   80 000061C0 mmioStringToFOURCCA
        132   81 000061D0 mmioStringToFOURCCW
        133   82 000061E0 mmioWrite
        134   83 0000FDE0 mmsystemGetVersion
        135   84 0000EC90 sndPlaySoundA
        136   85 0000ECA0 sndPlaySoundW
        137   86 00003060 timeBeginPeriod
        138   87 00003330 timeEndPeriod
        139   88 000061F0 timeGetDevCaps
        140   89 00006200 timeGetSystemTime
        141   8A 00002620 timeGetTime
        142   8B 00002F60 timeKillEvent
        143   8C 00002B80 timeSetEvent
        144   8D 00003340 waveInAddBuffer
        145   8E 00006210 waveInClose
        146   8F 00006220 waveInGetDevCapsA
        147   90 00006230 waveInGetDevCapsW
        148   91 00006240 waveInGetErrorTextA
        149   92 00006250 waveInGetErrorTextW
        150   93 00006260 waveInGetID
        151   94 00006270 waveInGetNumDevs
        152   95 00006280 waveInGetPosition
        153   96 00006290 waveInMessage
        154   97 000062A0 waveInOpen
        155   98 000062B0 waveInPrepareHeader
        156   99 000062C0 waveInReset
        157   9A 000062D0 waveInStart
        158   9B 000062E0 waveInStop
        159   9C 000062F0 waveInUnprepareHeader
        160   9D 00006300 waveOutBreakLoop
        161   9E 00006310 waveOutClose
        162   9F 00006320 waveOutGetDevCapsA
        163   A0 00006330 waveOutGetDevCapsW
        164   A1 00006340 waveOutGetErrorTextA
        165   A2 00006350 waveOutGetErrorTextW
        166   A3 00006360 waveOutGetID
        167   A4 00006370 waveOutGetNumDevs
        168   A5 00006380 waveOutGetPitch
        169   A6 00006390 waveOutGetPlaybackRate
        170   A7 00003350 waveOutGetPosition
        171   A8 000063A0 waveOutGetVolume
        172   A9 000063B0 waveOutMessage
        173   AA 000063C0 waveOutOpen
        174   AB 000063D0 waveOutPause
        175   AC 000063E0 waveOutPrepareHeader
        176   AD 000063F0 waveOutReset
        177   AE 00006400 waveOutRestart
        178   AF 00006410 waveOutSetPitch
        179   B0 00006420 waveOutSetPlaybackRate
        180   B1 00006430 waveOutSetVolume
        181   B2 00006440 waveOutUnprepareHeader
        182   B3 00006450 waveOutWrite
          2      00005B80 [NONAME]

  Summary

        2000 .data
        1000 .didat
        1000 .guids
        1000 .pdata
        7000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        5000 .rsrc
       10000 .text
```

Comment: а как можно сохранить адрес функции в отдельную переменную?

Comment: @War_Never_Changes Пример этого же кода с сохранением адреса в переменную [по этой ссылке](https://godbolt.org/z/jsjr3o), в конце адрес будет в func_addr, если он равен 0, значит функция с заданным именем не найдена в таблице. Имя функции которую надо найти я задал в func_name.

Comment: спасибо! выручил!